# Angular: Blur and empty a form field on click without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a form input which I would like to `blur` (de-focus) and empty when a button is clicked.

In AngularJS, I did this in the controller like so:

```
angular.element('#search-input').val('');
angular.element('#search-input').blur();
```

In Angular (4.4.4) I have it working like so:

```
$('#search-input').val('');
$('#search-input').blur();
```

But I'd rather not use jQuery.  What's the proper way to do this in Angular?

Here's the whole component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pb-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  private searchActive: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.searchActive = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleSearch = function () {
    if (this.searchActive) {
      this.searchActive = false;
      $('#search-input').val('');
      $('#search-input').blur();
    } else {
      this.searchActive = true;
    }

  };

}
```

Comment: Same approach but with vanilla JS functions would be `const ele = document.getElementById("search-input"); ele.blur(); ele.value = "";`

Comment: I get an error from webpack (and tslint): `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Comment: Yeah, there's no way typescript can know what kind of element will be returned by the `getElementById` function (if any at all), so you'll have to give it a little hint by casting to the proper element type. If it's an input element, you can use they type `HTMLInputElement`, so then the code would look like `const ele = document.getElementById("search-input") as HTMLInputElement; ...`

Comment: Use a Reactive Forms https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. Then you can use the method markaAsPristine, markAsdirty,etc.. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NgForm`s `reset` method:

```
@ViewChild(NgForm)
public form:NgForm;


form.reset(<value>);
```

Also there is no need for blur, since you are clicking button and it will take focus, if it does not, set `tabindex` attribute of the button.